# How do you add flow types for HOCs with conditional props

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to define an HOC that adds props if certain conditions are met, but I can't work out how to get this working.

Here's a crude example…

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'

type EnhancedProps = {| addFoo?: boolean |}
type BaseProps = {| foo?: string |}
type HOC =
  | (Component: React.ComponentType<{| foo: string |}>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: true}>
  | (Component: React.ComponentType<$Diff<BaseProps, { foo: string }>>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: false}>

const hoc: HOC = (Component) =>
  ({addFoo, ...props}) => {
    if (addFoo) {
      props = {...props, foo: 'Hi'}
    }
    (props: {...EnhancedProps, foo: string})
    return <Component {...props}/>;
  }


const BaseComponent = ({foo}: BaseProps) => `Hello`;

const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps> = hoc(BaseComponent);

<Enhanced />;
<Enhanced addFoo/>;
```

You can view the error on the Flow 'Try' pages here… https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32vK4CeGVUAFEAdgAtiI2lQAmABSYZyAXlABvAD4kZMgGKxYAfgBcoAEYHoNEaA0BfRHwGgAQmSoLYS0Ks2hIBiagpLjYKCIA5rYOToIAEgDyAMI+oIigtqAAFEnMWCJUIrim1HS4AHS5mLAFRQAq-FQAPH4BsKYhYZHRAHwAlD49lJwVVfmFuA0CTaISUrKe3gBk6sQ6+u2goQCuVHY96Zk5eTUTJSOVJ7WTjU0AJAAiKJCQTW6kHoqkADTq-gYdULhKL7fqDYZlS7Va5TZqzSTSeRfUArNRrPQA-zEaAffbIWg1EKgMSwWimRIpVTHaETAbKIaHDJM7Jo9YGX7lTkYL52OlDNSM5lM57ZdEbAYCgCQQqF3K8KnUnPKcqUvzaplYcRQrAcMuZur1GSyKtIpjUSvh8yR8rVmM6wN5gplHFw22wNiaY1ORUVXJ5wB6AG4nUyDTKQxlEASRET3lQvddUlk1G07KY44tSHzQAADOJUaBwHPBw1Rwn4S2I86QhMTWEzcQIhZfIaqEm0LJx2tFPolvWIBtzRGgAPBwdNmTaDGwUdAA

Or here are the actual errors…

```
12:         ({addFoo, ...props}) => {            ^ Could not decide which case to select. Since case 1 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type annotation to destructuring [3] or to return [4].
References:
8:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<{| foo: string |}>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: true}>                                                              ^ [1]
9:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<$Diff<BaseProps, { foo: string }>>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: false}>       ^ [2]
12:         ({addFoo, ...props}) => {
             ^ [3]
12:         ({addFoo, ...props}) => {
                                   ^ [4]
23: const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps> = hoc(BaseComponent);
                                        ^ boolean [1] is incompatible with boolean literal `true` [2] in property `addFoo`.
References:
5: type EnhancedProps = {| addFoo?: boolean |}
                                    ^ [1]
8:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<{| foo: string |}>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: true}>
                                                                                                           ^ [2]
23: const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps> = hoc(BaseComponent);
                                        ^ undefined [1] is incompatible with boolean literal `true` [2] in property `addFoo`.
References:
5: type EnhancedProps = {| addFoo?: boolean |}
                                    ^ [1]
8:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<{| foo: string |}>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: true}>
                                                                                                           ^ [2]
23: const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps> = hoc(BaseComponent);
                                                         ^ Cannot assign `hoc(...)` to `Enhanced` because `React.ComponentType` [1] is not an object.
References:
9:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<$Diff<BaseProps, { foo: string }>>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: false}>
                   ^ [1]
23: const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps> = hoc(BaseComponent);
                                                         ^ all branches are incompatible: Either inexact `React.ComponentType` [1] is incompatible with exact `React.Element` [2]. Or `React.ComponentType` [1] is incompatible with `React.Portal` [3]. Or property `@@iterator` is missing in `React.ComponentType` [1] but exists in `$Iterable` [4].
References:
9:   | (Component: React.ComponentType<$Diff<BaseProps, { foo: string }>>) => React.ComponentType<EnhancedProps & {addFoo: false}>                                                                              ^ [1]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.89.0/flowlib/react.js:18:   | React$Element<any>                                                  ^ [2]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.89.0/flowlib/react.js:19:   | React$Portal                                                  ^ [3]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.89.0/flowlib/react.js:20:   | Iterable<?React$Node>;
                                                  ^ [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've missed is:

> Intersections of exact object types may not work as you expect. If you
>   need to combine exact object types, use object type spread.

[doc](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types)

Also, it's better to use [generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) for hoc, as wrapped component props might be specific per component.

```
import * as React from 'react'

type EnhancedProps = {| addFoo?: boolean |}
type BaseProps = {| foo?: string |}

const hoc = <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<{...EnhancedProps, ...T}> => 
        ({addFoo, ...props}) => {
          if (addFoo) {
              props = {...props, foo: 'Hi'}
          }
          (props: {...T, ...EnhancedProps})
          return <Component {...props}/>;
        }


const BaseComponent = ({foo}: BaseProps) => `Hello`;

const Enhanced: React.ComponentType<{...BaseProps, ...EnhancedProps}> = hoc<BaseProps>(BaseComponent);

<Enhanced />;
<Enhanced addFoo/>;
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32vK4CeGVUAFEAdgAtiI2lQAmABSYZyAXlABvAD4kZMgGKxYAfgBcoAEYHoNEaA0BfRHwGgAQmSoLYS0Ks2hIBiagpLjYKCIA5rYOiLSwIiGgYrC0PqAAPAAqAHwAFADCzFgiVCK4ptR0uAB0hZjxpbiZ-FRZ2QCUFZw1dcWNzQLpatUjohJSsp5KADSgI9WZdtk+y4ig6xvruWrEOvqws-MYiqR27Svqa5vXKJCgubt6BudqiACQ19fHXirqRyezAKwUysAASKFYDk+myh0K23yUpmGI0yh1G4kk0nkJzOVzhHFwAFdsDZ0r0GmU-iMEadgNkANx466wz5MzaxeKJNykKjkkqU1TbIF2Uzcjwnc7KZYAA1BVGgcGljLhHIS+DGmNkXSqtSKFKaLSG8zFU1IaOqGom2J+SzSyVo6RNJzyYr5jXayuhiHSlqxoDpjJ9GKt2iesADQA)